# Will a Samsung refrigerator door cam marked "L" also fit the right door?

Tags: refrigerator, appliances, samsung

My fridge is model RH25H5611SR/AA. [When I search for that model number on SamsungParts.com](http://www.samsungparts.com/partslist.aspx?Catalog=Parts_and_Accessories&Category=RH25H5611SR), and then [search for "cam"](http://www.samsungparts.com/partslist.aspx?Catalog=Parts_and_Accessories&Category=RH25H5611SR) I see parts listed but they all have an "L" in their name. I'm guessing these are for the left door? My right door does not close, I want to replace the cam on that door.

The part it suggests that seems most-applicable is,

> DA66-00696A CAM HINGE-RISER LOW L

Does that part work on both the left and right the door the unit is split door with one door for the fridge and one for the freezer. [You can see the pictures at Lowes.com](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Samsung-5201-27-4-cu-ft-Side-by-Side-Refrigerator-with-Single-Ice-Maker-Fingerprint-Resistant-Stainless-Steel-ENERGY-STAR/5001626411)?

[image: Samsung RH25H5611SR/AA1]

If it doesn't work on the right door, what mechanism is responsible for the left door not closing fully?

---

Here is what my parts actually look like

[image: Lower right door cam (door mount)]
[image: Lower right door cam (fridge mount)]
[image: Lower right door cam (fridge mount)]

Comment: Does the cam have its part number on it? Is it symmetric? Does the door not close at all, or not close on its own?

Comment: @AndrewMorton the door closes but not on its own. It require force. I haven't taken both doors off to see if it's symmetric. I was trying to save that work.. The doors themselves are pretty similar -- it's a split door fridge one door for freezer, one for fridge. That's more or less my question here -- does Samsung just provide an "L" part for these models that function as an "R" part too?

Comment: Could it be that a hinge screw has come loose? If you hold the edge of the door while it is open, can you lift it more than a couple of millimetres, or feel some a wobble in any other direction?

Comment: Is it marked "L" for _left_, or "L" for _lower?_

Comment: @gnicko not going to lie. that's a **REALLY** good question and I never entertained that.

Comment: @gnicko but either way whatever part is listed in samsungparts.com looks nothing like the pictures I took

Answer (score 3):

A quick search for "CAM HINGE-RISER LOW R" clears this right up. The part is clearly not symmetrical, so it will not work on the right door.

The correct part number for that seems to be [DA66-00559A](http://www.samsungparts.com/Products/Parts_and_Accessories/PID-DA66-00559A.aspx). Be sure to verify before purchase.

Comment: That model does not list `RH25H5611SR` as a supported model, and it's not listed as a part on the page for `RH25H5611SR`. =/

Comment: It looks to me like the right door has a completely different hinge strategy. See the #14 cluster at https://www.appliancepartspros.com/cabinet-parts-for-samsung-rh25h5611sr-aa-0000.html.